# Wildcard url in Django using re_path

Tags: django, django-urls

As per Django documentation ,below url pattern will work for

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/index` . But I want also to make it work for

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/index/`
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/json/index/`

```
from django.urls import include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
]
```

How we can achieve it using `re_path`

Comment: you can add all these patterns in the `urlpatterns`.

Comment: `urlpatterns` for prefix (/api , /api/json) for a string `index` I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple entries of `re_path` with different urls endpoints for same `views.index` like this .

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^api/json/index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^api/index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Is there any other `efficient` way to do this. This is pretty tedious since I have many such APIs

Comment: is there a pattern in your urls?

Comment: Yes , all the prefix should be like `api/json/` or `api/xml/` or `api/`

Comment: take a look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs